# Excel Issues macro may be needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I trying to compare lists in excel.  There are two lists, one list just has one column and the other has two columns, and what I am trying to do is when column A matches column C than take the value in column D and use that to replace column A.

For example:

```
Column A  Column B Column C Column D
Blue               Blue     Shirt   
Blue               Red      Pants
Red                Green    Shoes
Red
Green
Green
Purple

So the completed list should look like:

Column A  Column B Column C Column D
Shirt              Blue     Shirt   
Shirt              Red      Pants
Pants              Green    Shoes
Pants
Shoes
Shoes
Purple
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work until you hit an error. And then it stops working. Not sure why, maybe you or someone else could fix it, but it will work for your selection as long as your selection is found (e.g. "purple" breaks the loop)

```
Sub test()
Dim a As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next

Err.Clear

For Each c In Selection

a = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c, Range("C1:D3"), 2, False)

If Err.Number = 0 Then c.Value = a

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In another column (e.g. B), enter the following formula and fill down:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$C$1:$D$3,2,FALSE),A1)
```

Then copy the resulting column, and Paste Special -> Values only over column A.  Then you can delete the formulas from Column B.